# to manipulate the DOM of the current page using PHP?

Tags: php, html, dom

I would like to know how to manipulate the DOM of the current page using PHP. The explanation is as below:

This is the code in my PHP file:

```
<div id="edittitle" title="Editing title">
<b>1</b>
</div>
$strhtml=;
    libxml_use_internal_errors( true );
    $dom=new DOMDocument('1.0','utf-8');
    $dom->validateOnParse=false;
    $dom->loadHTML( $strhtml );
    libxml_clear_errors();
    $col=$dom->getElementsByTagName('b');
    echo $col->item(0)->nodeValue;
```

Actually, what I want is putting the whole html code that exists in the current file (the PHP file) in the variable `$strhtml` (Please focus on the following line of my code: `$strhtml=;`). Is there any idea about how to do that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Don't fully understand the purpose, can you explain a little more?

Comment: Based on your previous questions I have the feeling you're on a completely wrong path here. What exactly are you trying to accomplish? And not on the level of "passing X from PHP to Javascript" or whatever; tell us what feature you're trying to implement.

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to you can do this by putting all of your HTML in an output buffer while / before sending it to the browser (the latter can be easily done with [output control](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/ref.outcontrol.php)). Then you can DOM parse the "captured" HTML.

But you should ask yourself what you are really trying to achieve and if this is not better suited for client-side (i.e. Javascript) code.

Comment: Well, could you tell me what changes exactly should I make in my code please?

Comment: It can't be done with simple changes to your example. You need to rethink why and how you are doing this.

Answer (score 0):

PHP is a server-side language and is **only** executed on the server, any DOM manipulations must be handled by client-side Javascript.

http://callmenick.com/post/basics-javascript-dom-manipulation